# Will all the memory occupied by a process will GCed after this process is killed

Tags: android

I am once confused in one case, for example I dynamtically registered a broadcast receiver without unregistering it anywhere and that is a typical memory leak, right? Then the application process is closed, so will the GC fix that memory leak by freeing the memory? thanks!

Comment: post it in the AndroidEntusiastic section.

Answer (score 1):

The garbage collector makes unaccessible memory areas again usable within the process.

When the process is killed its associated memory is given back to the OS to be reused for other processes.

So in your case, it is not really the GC that reclaims the memory but the normal process termination procedure.